# HUD section 8 benefits -- community service exemptions

Tags: united-states, housing

Regarding the HUD (Housing and Urban Development) policy for Area Housing Assistance ([general page](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/24/part-960/subpart-F), [specific definitions](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/24/960.603), and [exempt status](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/607#d) mainly what the question is about, definition for "[work activities](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/24/960.601)").

Their exemption policy from 8 hours of monthly community service includes a list of characteristics (like over 62  etc..) but then states:

> "Is engaged in work activities"

and it says below that this includes (I'm leaving some things out):

> "Work experience" (including work associated with the refurbishing of
>   publicly assisted housing) if sufficient private sector employment is
>   not available

My main questions are simply, what does "work experience" entail? It seems like they want you to slave away at the "publicly assisted housing" organizations, but if someone is merely volunteering somewhere, or gets "work experience" from some other location would that also count?

And what is the specific definition of that? I couldn't find any source.

Also what if someone is self employed --- what kind of verification would be able to be provided for that?

Not only that, but part of community service is volunteering at local non-profits etc.... but what if you own your own non-profit?